# How to optimize formula performance?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using following formula to filter data to get list of todays delivery challan.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$K$49999,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$1:$A$49999)/($A$1:$A$49999=TODAY()),ROW(1:1)),COLUMN(B$1)),"")
```

Below is my data screenshot.

[image]

[Sample File Download Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dUPf6HBEq2w4thiC8vV11Rjq3NPu46pw/view?usp=sharing)

What is question?
When I change any date to todays date it works very slow. When I use this formula to other sheet then it works really very very slow. Can anyone suggest me to optimize performance of this formula or to use other formula to filter data based on condition? My data will increase on daily basis.

Comment: Aggregate is an array type formula,  The best method would be vba in an Worksheet change Event that uses either normal filter or advanced filter to return the list.  Formulas will be slow.

Comment: @ScottCraner I thought that. It is better for if I can use regular formula otherwise I will go with `VBA`. Can you please suggest me any code to get best performance.

Comment: I have code to filter data based on condition and copy `Visible` cells to another sheet.

Answer (score 0):

The sample data you've entered, only contains 837 rows, and you are dealing almost 50.000, which is far too large. Isn't it possible to create a name (like `mytable`, referring to your table), update this name's definition every time a row gets added, and just use this name or region?

Comment: That could be a good idea. But the file will be used by production floor user. They are not most aware/expert user. That is my concern. I will test with table and feedback.